# Huge unwanted artboard created by default in Adobe Illustrator CC 2020

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I am using Adobe Illustrator CC 25.2.1 on Windows 10 Pro.

After launching Illustrator, I click "Create new" and choose "HDV/HDTV 1080" document type under the *Film & Video* tab.

When I do this, the artboard with the selected specification is created but is placed within another, giant artboard of dimensions 14400 px by 14400 px.  I have to manually delete the larger artboard.

Is this default behavior or do I have some setting off in my configuration?

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a default behavior when using any of the film and video presets. You can delete the second artboard and create a new preset. Not sure why this happens.

Comment: @AndrewH Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following explanation in this book: The Adobe Illustrator WOW! Book for CS6 and CC 2e (Steuer) [2019]

[image]

So the larger artboard is being created in preparation for importing into AE.